siunitx \micro font problem
In siunitx v3.3.21 a warning was issued "Option "math-micro" has been removed."
running LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024)
code for desired siunitx \micro output:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI{62.5}{\micro\metre} is the measurement.
\end{document}


I am trying the following to get non-serif text with the above siunitx appearance of \micro using:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI{62.5}{\micro\metre} is the measurement.
\end{document}

results in:

only \micro appears like this.  Any ideas as to how to remedy?
here is desired output for clarification:


Welcome to TeX. SE! With editing you completely change what is your problem. Now seems that you like to have units in serif fonts and main text in sans serif. Right?

Thanks for the welcome Zarko. Incorrect again Zarko.  I only added the 3rd image for clarification, I did not completely change the problem. Look at the unedited 2nd image carefully. siunitx has a sans serif \micro with a serif meter. That is the issue. I would like everything siunitx outputs to be serif, while the body is sans serif. As far as I can tell, siunitx only outputs the \micro as sans serif while it's neighbouring meter is serif

As  said in my co0mment, but in the first version of question, this was not clear (a case) ..., it can be concluded, that you like to have number and units in sand serif fonts. To my opinion, this is more consistent (and nicer) in comparison what you like to achieve ...

Zarko, Incorrect again.  The number and units are to be serif, the body sans serif.  All three images clearly show serif for siunitx output (except what I believe to be a discrepancy in the case of \micro. I did not ask what your opinion was. I believe ISO 80000 states SI units should be in roman -  (serif).

What would be the reason of typesetting number and units in serif type also in sans serif context? ISO 80000 states that units and digits should be upright. It specifies nothing about the font: you're reading too much in “Roman”.

If you download the English version of the BIPM brochure from https://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure you can read at section 2.3.1 that the unit should be typeset in upright (roman) font. The “roman” is possibly added for reinforcing the “upright” main attribute.

egreg, I did read too much into ``roman'', I've `set' and 'forget' everything I needed regarding fonts over 8 years ago.  Forgetting that roman has both serif and sans versions.

Please note that \SI has been deprecated for at least a couple of years by now. Do start to use \qty instead of \SI.
For this answer, I will assume that your document uses the default serif font family. For the article document class, as well as for many other document classes, this default font family is Computer Modern -- or its very close relative, Latin Modern.
If the output of \SI{62.5}{\micro\metre} must be rendered entirely in the default serif font family, I suggest you add the instruction
\sisetup{text-font-command=\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont}

after loading siunitx. (If your document uses a non-default text font, what to use instead of lmr will depend on how exactly the text font(s) are being loaded. Please ask a new question if this issue applies to your document.)

% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article} % '10pt' is the default
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{text-font-command=\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
\qty{62.5}{\micro\metre} is the measurement.
\end{document}


This is working.  Carefully going over every bit of info you provided.  I use arial for default and the lmr/cmr versions of sisetup works and both appear indistinguishable to me.  Now your solution does everything the default siunitx setting does except it uses the lmr/cmr version of the \micro symbol. Any idea why the \micro symbol doesn't just default to the lmr/cmr version?

@MJT - Not sure what you mean by "except it uses the lmr/cmr version of the \micro symbol". The cmr/lmr version is the default, i.e., it's identical to what you would get if you made no font changes at all in your document. Aside: As LMR is derived from CMR, you'll see no difference at all if you use only unaccented letters, numerals, and symbols.

My MWE is as small as I could make it. I assume siunitx would use default math font even though the body was changed to default sans.  Don't you find it strange that the \micro symbol changed from one example to the next? Why is it sans even though it is sitting between the serif numerals and serif unit?

@MJT - You're asking me a why-type question. I'm very sorry if i have somehow created the impression that I have had any kind of say in the design choices embedded in the siunitx package. That is not the case. Please ask why-type questions to the author and maintainer of the siunitx package. You'll find his name and email address on the first page of the user guide of the package.

Declare your main text font, rather than redefining \familydefault. Next use mode=text and an appropriate text-font-command:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} %%% NO

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\newfontfamily{\lmr}{Latin Modern Roman}

\sisetup{
  mode=text,
  text-font-command=\lmr,
}

\begin{document}

\qty{62.5}{\micro\metre} is the measurement.

$\qty{12}{\meter\per\second}$

\end{document}


However, I nowhere read in the BIPM brochure that numbers and units should be typeset in a serif font: they say upright.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Sans}

\sisetup{
  mode=text,
}

\begin{document}

\qty{62.5}{\micro\metre} is the measurement.

$\qty{12}{\meter\per\second}$

\end{document}



egreg, I think you are getting into the weeds here.  I'd have to ask separate questions w.r.t. \familydefault and \setmainfont because somewhere in time I setup babel and it appears to interfere with \setmainfont.  The key takeaway I was driving at was why \micro would render as sans while nested in between serif numerals and serif units when all the other SI prefixes render as serif under as default conditions as I could come up with.

@MJT I can only answer what you ask, not what you thought to have asked. If you want a document in sans serif, set the main font as sans serif, that's so easy.

I've made the changes you suggested. I thought \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} set the main font as sans serif.  Used it for over 8 years.  Why is this no good? just curious.

@MJT The main font is still either Latin Modern Roman or the one declared by \setmainfont. In my opinion there's no reason to use \setsansfont and then change \familydefault; just don't use \sffamily, of course, or set also `\setsansfont.

Edit:
From your first version of question I conclude, that complete units as well number quantity number should be  written with in sans serif fonts as is written other text in your document. My conclusion is also in accordance with BIPM (see @eqreg comment).
First version of answer:
With correct syntax of siunitx package after version 3 this can be accomplished with siunitx option mode=match:
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{sansmath}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{mode=match}    % <---

\begin{document}
\qty{62.5}{\micro\metre} is the measurement.
\end{document}


